# Status bar in Java

Tags: java, jsp

I have 2 different kind of flow for status bar on top of my webage. I have to pass value to this status bar class to let it know which flow to follow depending upon the user selection in the main page. If ID = 1 than follow 1 style of flow and if ID = 2 than follow other style of flow. And also if ID = 1 and step = 2 than I have to diplay one style of flow with 2nd step in the status bar.I am stuck like how can I get that flow moving from one page to another when user done with 1 page and moves to other. How can I keep track of that and display correct status bar on the top of the page. How can I get that status and step in the flow to display it right on that particular page. I have done this so far I need some jsp content holder in jsp page to display what ever I get return from that url connection and I need to pass id to this class to see which flow I have to follow. Any help would be great..

```
public class StatusBar 
{
    private static final String STATUS_URL = 'http://10.1.2.3:8080/status';

    private final String buffer;
    public String toString(){ return buffer; }

    private final String id;
    private final String step;


    private ProgressBar( Create create )
    {
        id = Create.pbid;
        step = Create.step;

        String response = "";

            Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put( "id", id );
            m.put( "step", step );

            String query = buildQuery( m );

            URL url = new URL( STATUS_URL );

            URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
            uc.setDoOutput( true );
            uc.setAllowUserInteraction( false );
            uc.setConnectTimeout( 5000 );
            uc.setReadTimeout( 5000 );

            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream( uc.getOutputStream() );
            ps.print( query );
            ps.close();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( uc.getInputStream(), "UTF-8" ));
            StringCreate sb = new StringCreate();
            String line;

            while(( line = br.readLine()) != null )
            {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append( "\n" );
            }

            br.close();
            response = sb.toString();

            buffer = "";
    }


    private static final String buildQuery( Map<String, String> args ) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        StringCreate sb = new StringCreate();

        for( Map.Entry<String, String> entry : args.entrySet() ) 
        {
            sb.append( URLEncoder.encode( entry.getKey(), "UTF-8" ));          
            sb.append( '=' );
            sb.append( URLEncoder.encode( entry.getValue(), "UTF-8" ));          
            sb.append( '&' );
        }

        return sb.toString().substring( 0, sb.length() - 1 );
    }


    public static class Create
    {
        private String id;
        private String step;

        public Create(){}

        public Create id( String val )
        {
            id = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Create step( int val )
        {
            step = String.valueOf( val );
            return this;
        }

        public StatusBar build()
        {
                return new StatusBar( this );

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From you description I believe that you need to store status (or state) somewhere while user traverses your pages.

This something is [HTTP Session](http://glassfish.java.net/nonav/javaee5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html). You can store values there and they will be accessible during user session on your site.

In JSP you set something in session using JSTL: `<c:set var="foo" value="bar" scope="session"/>` and access it (retrieve the value back) just using `${foo}`.

Use that in your status bar JSP code.

In case I misunderstood your question you can provide a better description of what you really want to achieve, what you tried so far, and why your attempts failed.